caber in different expressions
I came across this sentence in El País (article about Trump and Musk)

Cabe preguntarse: si este colonialismo espacial se hiciera realidad algún día, ¿cuántos y quiénes habría en esas naves?

My question is about the verb ''caber''
The RAE states ''caber ''can be used if something is possible.

intr. Ser posible o natural.
and
there are other expressions like ''no cabe más'' which I don't understand.

I have come across ''no cabe duda'' which seems to mean ''no doubt ''or undoubtedly.
Also, ''no cabe ninguna duda'' meaning ''don't be in any doubt'' .
I checked with Google Translate and it says ''cabe que'' means ''it is no wonder''.
This is from the El País article.
Is this so? It doesn't seem to fit with the other meanings.
I also recall seeing ''caber'' used in relation to space and crowds ''no cabe ni el alfiler''.
Is ''caber'' like ''echar' and  maybe a few other verbs in that it is used in a lot of phrases?
I can't seem to see an equivalent verb to translate ''caber'' in English.

You should extract and add the paragraph from which you took the sentence. That interview is only for subscribers to read, which makes the link suspicious of being spam.

The definition you copied into your question seems to cover the examples in your question, as you described them: "no cabe duda" -> "no doubt is possible", "cabe que" -> "it is natural that". Which phrases are you unsure about? Could you [edit] to be more specific?

Apologies. Here is the specific phrase:     Cabe preguntarse: si este colonialismo espacial se hiciera realidad algún día, ¿cuántos y quiénes habría en esas naves?    What is this ''cabe preguntarse'' exactly? Again, it is this use of ''caber''in different phrases and I believe ,it is not directly translatable to English. What exactly is ''caber''itself first of all?

Please stop thinking that google translate et al will help you. Look at the RAE definitions and work on those, or a really good bilingual dictionary like Harrap's. Cabe preguntarse=It makes sense to ask oneself. OR We should ask ourselves. Also, caber means fit, like for clothes. No cade ninguna duda=there is no doubt.

There is a phrase in English,  "there is no room for doubt"  that conveys the same notion as "no cabe duda".  It's the strange concept that doubt takes up space.

@Walter Mitty. Yes, that's right. Therefore, both Spanish and English have the same idea idiomatically.

En el Diccionario panhispánico de dudas se encuentra recogida la acepción que menciona tac
caber

b) 'Ser posible'. El sujeto puede ser un sustantivo, una oración de
infinitivo o una oración subordinada introducida por que: «Y ante eso
no cabe otra postura que dimitir» (País [Esp.] 3.6.1980); «Dentro de
este conjunto cabría distinguir varios grupos» (Chaparro Integración
[Ven. 1991]); «Cabe que el juez diga que la decisión adoptada por él
es jurídicamente correcta, pero moralmente injusta» (Atienza Justicia
[Esp. 1993]). También puede significar 'ser preciso o necesario': «Sin
embargo, cabe señalar la posible existencia de efectos estacionales en
estos meses» (Hoy [Chile] 19-25.1.83).

Con lo cual podríamos "reconstruir" la frase como:

Es necesario preguntarse: si este colonialismo espacial se hiciera realidad algún día, ¿cuántos y quiénes habría en esas naves?

o

Podríamos plantearnos lo siguiente: si este colonialismo espacial se hiciera realidad algún día, ¿cuántos y quiénes habría en esas naves?

En cualquier caso, creo que esa parte de la oración solo sirve para introducir la pregunta. Si la omitimos no se pierde significado alguno.

Si este colonialismo espacial se hiciera realidad algún día, ¿cuántos y quiénes habría en esas naves?



Cabe preguntarse: si este colonialismo espacial se hiciera realidad algún día, ¿cuántos y quiénes habría en esas naves?

La acepción que está presente de caber es la de ‘ser apropiado, adecuado o pertinente’. Una llamada del deber.
Cabe preguntarse = Deberíamos preguntarnos = Sería apropiado preguntarnos
Nueva acepción para agregar al diccionario? Supongo, en principio deriva de la acepción de ‘ser posible’ pero la adecuación o lo propio de un hecho va más allá de lo posible por lo que puede ser difícil inferir este sentido del término.

Gracias.  sí,tiene sentido. En inglés, decimos''should we ask/is it appropriate to ask''.

@Bluelion7 cabe preguntarse is not should we ask; it's we should ask

Caber="to fit", "to fit in". The use in the sentences you ask about does not use a separate meaning, but rather  use the verb in a way that you don't see in English.
No cabe ninguna duda = "there's no room for any doubt" (literally: "no doubt fits").
No cabe ni un alfiler = "there's no room at all" (literally: "not even a pin fits")
Cabe preguntarse = "It makes sense to ask ourselves" (literally: "it fits to ask ourselves").

.@ RubioRic.  Great. All that makes sense,thank you

I think you directed your comment to another answer :)

@Bluelion7 You're welcome :-) Sorry for not translating my answer. I think that it's clear in any case
